# I have the error when run the 'conda -V' and any conda command

Tags: python, anaconda

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:\ana\Lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 17, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "E:\ana\Lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 54, in main_subshell
        parser = generate_parser(add_help=True)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "E:\ana\Lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 127, in generate_parser
        configure_parser_plugins(sub_parsers)
      File "E:\ana\Lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 354, in configure_parser_plugins
        else set(find_commands()).difference(plugin_subcommands)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "E:\ana\Lib\site-packages\conda\cli\find_commands.py", line 71, in find_commands
        for entry in os.scandir(dir_path):
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    OSError: [WinError 123] 文件名、目录名或卷标语法不正确。: ':\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\bin'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.